# Fetch the last filled cell per row in a given range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, worksheet-function

I would like to have a formula in column B, which fetches the data from the last non-blank cell in the range D:H. I have hard-plugged the data in column B to highlight what the desired formula should give me in the end >> the latest value on the timeline.

I have not figured out how to solve this issue using a formula, which would not require a concatenation of `IF` clauses.

[image: screenshot of table]

Answer (score 0):

Try, in B2

```
=index(D2:2,(MATCH(9^9, D2:2,1)))
```

Comment: How does the 9^9 work ? I am asking because it fetches me a date for values like "6.65"

Comment: 9^9 is a large number, the formula tries to find the value immediately less than that value, that is the last. I have tried with 6.65 and it works fine, do you have a formatted cell?

Comment: with a formatted cell you could get 1/5/1900 15:36:00 !!

Answer (score 0):

If you put this formula in column b, it will grab the farthest value to the right, which I think is what you want to do?

```
=SUBSTITUTE(right(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("?",TRUE,D2:H2),"?",REPT("!",50)),20),"!","")
```